# How to 'move' babel-runtime into a webpack vendors DLL?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm creating two webpack bundles: `vendors.dll.js` and `client.js`.

Vendors is created with webpack.DllPlugin. It includes all front-end modules in `node_modules/`. This is working great.

Client includes my app code. It uses the webpack.DllReferencePlugin to delegate to the DLL for vendors. This is working great.

Client runs all javascript through `babel-loader`. I'm using the `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` plugin, which causes a whole mess of core-js stuff to be compiled into my client bundle. I'd prefer to move that stuff into the DLL, since it won't change as frequently as the app.

AFAIK you cannot just include `babel-runtime` in the DLL (I tried this). From what I can tell the core-js stuff is loaded more directly, and babel-runtime doesn't even have a `main` from what I can tell.

Babel: 6.x
Webpack: 1.x

Happy to provide actual config if its needed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could scan the required directories and include all files like this.

```
const readDir = dir => {
  const result = [];
  fs.readdirSync(dir).map(file => {
    if (file.match(/\.js$/)) result.push(`${dir.replace('./node_modules/', '')}/${file}`);
    else if (fs.lstatSync(dir + '/' + file).isDirectory()) result.push(...readDir(dir + '/' + file));
  });
  return result
}
const babelRuntimeHelpers = readDir('./node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers');
const babelRuntimeCoreJs = readDir('./node_modules/babel-runtime/core-js');
```

And then add those to your vendor array:

```
vendor: [
    ...babelRuntimeHelpers,
    ...babelRuntimeCoreJs,
    ...rest
]
```